# Client Side Validations + simple_form in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, client-side-validation

When I put the following in my gemfile:

```
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'client_side_validations'#, github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'#, github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form'
```

It results in this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.0)

    client_side_validations-simple_form was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      client_side_validations (~> 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
        rails (< 4.3.0, >= 4.0.0)
```

Any ideas on getting these gems to work?

Comment: I just got `unanswer` on my post and I am not sure why as it includes all facts: (1) gem does not have production-ready solution for Rails 5. (2) you can use experimental branch as suggested in provided link. Newer post has been marked as the answer, but it provides the same solution (using experimental branch) without the notice that it is still WIP. @bevanb could you clarify the reason?

Comment: @smefju Sorry for the late response- I got the issue resolved using the other solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use client_side_validations with Rails 5 by specifying the branch like this:

```
gem 'client_side_validations', 
    github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations', 
    branch: 'rails5'
```

And if using Simple Form:

```
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form', 
    github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form', 
    branch: 'rails5'
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5 support is not ready for the `client_side_validations` gem. Take a look at this issue [#645](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/issues/645). You can try experimental branch as suggested in the issue's comment.